# How get a Document object of HTMLIFrameElement in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, iframe, gwt2

I have [object HTMLIFrameElement] an I'd like to get its document. I would rather do it without native method. This is what I try now, but it doiesn't work.

```
//This is iFrame container with iFrame
mainWidge = new MainWidgetViewImpl(base);
//This is HTMLIFrameElement
Element iframeElement = mainWidge.getElement().getFirstChildElement();
//I've tried this, but it gets null pointer exception
IFrameElement iframe = (IFrameElement)mainWidge.getElement().getFirstChildElement();
//Here is: "Cannot read property 'document' of null"
Document doc = iframe.getContentDocument();
```

Answer (score 1):

That would meant the iframe's `contentWindow` is `null`, which would be the case if the iframe is not attached to the document.

> The `contentWindow` IDL attribute must return the `WindowProxy` object of the `iframe` element's nested browsing context, if any, or null otherwise.

— *Source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-iframe-contentwindow*

> When an `iframe` element is inserted into a document that has a browsing context, the user agent must create a nested browsing context, and then process the `iframe` attributes for the "first time".
>
> When an `iframe` element is removed from a document, the user agent must discard the nested browsing context, if any.

— *Source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element*

Comment: My goal is to inject stylesheet into iframe's head section before it is displayed. Id there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Attaching the iframe to the document does not necessarily mean making it visible.

Comment: This is some kind of solution. But I'd rather inject these styles before onLoad event. So they are available form the beginning.